# Designing a client/host network game

Tags: data-structures, network-programming

I am currently implementing a game and want to add a Network feature. (i.e. I want to be able to join and host my application/game). This seems a lot tougher than I first imagined. The purpose of this question is asking if there is a good general datastructure choice for these kind of implementations.

My main problem is that I currently have a lot of functions in my Game class that look like this:

`f() { if (host) doSomething() else doSomethingCompletelyDifferent() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use OOP. Alas, you do not provide which programming language you use.

For example, if you are programming in C, you could do

```
struct thefunctions {
    void (*stuff1)(void);
    void (*stuff2)(int);
    int (*get)(int);
};

struct thefunctions network {
    .stuff1 = doSomething;
}

struct thefunctions standalone {
    .stuff1 = doSomethingCompletelyDifferent;
}

struct thefunctions * funcs;

[...]

if (host) {
    funcs = &network;
} else {
    funcs = &standalone;
}

// now the structs are initialized. We can now use funcs->.

[...]

// If I am sure that stuff1 has been initialited properly, I can do
funcs->stuff1();

// If not, I should check first
if (funcs->stuff1) funcs->stuff1();

// or
assert(funcs->stuff1);
funcs->stuff1();
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't write server and client code in the same class for a Network app.   Perhaps you could consider ServerGame and ClientGame classes which both derive from the same Interface or base class.

As for any other specific Data structures, I believe that would very much depend on the platform you're writing for and the language which you're using (for example, in the world of .NET you might be able to take advantage of WCF to hide away a lot of the low-level networking stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to approach this is to always have a game server. Then you can play locally, or you can join a networked game hosted on your machine, or someone elses.

Job one is to split out which functionality you need on teh server and which on the client. In general it's UI in the client, and logic/storage in the server.

Data structures are hugely game dependant, how easy it will be to switch over will depend on your current code, but client server is the way to go.